# Commands specific to gvim

Tags: vim

I am trying to clean my .vimrc by removing gui specific settings so that it works well with terminal (i.e., when I start vim over ssh . Is there a place to find a list of vim commands that I should move within `if ('gui_running')  endif` block.

Answer (score 4):

No, only common sense will help you, there. If you want to clean up your `~/.vimrc` it must mean that you have identified some problems, doesn't it?

In general only a few things are really GUI-specific:

- `guifont` and related options,
- a colorscheme that works only in a GUI,
- removing the menu or scroll bars with `guioptions`,
- any option starting with `gui`, actually,
- mappings that work only in the GUI…

Read the documentation for every option you set.

But if that's really *your* `~/.vimrc` it shouldn't be too hard because you know exactly what everything does, how and why, right?

As an example, this is what I have:

```
let os=substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')

if has('gui_running')
  colorscheme sorcerer

  set guioptions-=T

  set lines=40
  set columns=140

  if os == 'Darwin'
    set guifont=Inconsolata-g:h13
    set fuoptions=maxvert,maxhorz
    set clipboard^=unnamed

  elseif os == 'Linux'
    set guifont=Inconsolata-g\ Medium\ 11
    set guioptions-=m
    set clipboard^=unnamedplus

  endif

else
  if &t_Co >= 256
    colorscheme sorcerer

  elseif &t_Co < 256
    colorscheme sorcerer_16

  endif

  if os == 'Darwin'
    set clipboard^=unnamed

  elseif os == 'Linux'
    set clipboard^=unnamedplus

  endif

  nnoremap <Esc>A <up>
  nnoremap <Esc>B <down>
  nnoremap <Esc>C <right>
  nnoremap <Esc>D <left>
  inoremap <Esc>A <up>
  inoremap <Esc>B <down>
  inoremap <Esc>C <right>
  inoremap <Esc>D <left>

endif
```

I don't use this `~/.vimrc` on remote machines so the `clipboard` settings are safe for me but you might need to put it in a conditional if you intend to work via SSH.

Comment: “But if that's really your ~/.vimrc it shouldn't be too hard because you know exactly what everything does, how and why, right?” As any software, vimrc settings can be written in a write-only manner. With folding it is easy to divide it into parts which are edited separately and have different level of understanding. Especially if you last edited them a few years ago. 3–5 years and even the cleanest code looks like it is written by a foreigner, though cleanest code is definitely easier to relearn. But vimrc is not a thing you have many reasons to write in a clean manner… So wrong.

Comment: @ZyX, as an SO veteran, you should know that that write-only manner is often a recipe for disaster: a messy vimrc makes a messy config and a messy config breaks plugins. I couldn't tell you the whole content of my vimrc from memory, of course, but when I read it I know exactly what does what and, if the exact working of an option is not clear it's easy enough to find out. A clean something is always better than a dirty something, especially when many other things depend on that something.

Comment: I had vimrc like this for years until it was refactored to use frawor. Not used mappings, commands and functions do not contribute to any problems except for memory usage, problems with options are normally seen and fixed immediately. As I normally do not add anything complex to the vimrc there is not much motivation to keep it clean. It should be kept searchable though, but that is why I have folds that divide vimrc into sections. I would not doubt that clean is better, but I can say “exactly what everything does, how and why” for my vimrc because I know VimL, not because I know my vimrc.

Comment: @ZyX, "you" an "I" (to a smaller extent) know what we do. But if our mutual experience serves as an indicator that's not really the case for everyone. Many questions here could have been avoided if the askers took a little more care of their configuration and didn't mindlessly paste stuff without ever reading the doc. Using folding in your vimrc is "clean" and, somehow, I doubt you are the kind of person to have a `set noai` at line 72 and a `set ai` at line 513 (just an innocuous example).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you are looking for, but this should provide you with a starting point.

[Vim GUI Documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html)